# RAM usage - Will resizing an open window make it use less RAM?

Tags: ram, window

I have Lubuntu running on my laptop (which has a memory of 512 MB, if I may add) and it does it's job. But when I run programs like Opera or Atom, it lagged a bit, when I switched tabs or something.

I resized the window(by default it was maximized) and it seemed to me that it ran faster now.

Is this just an illusion or does this really happen ? If this really does happen, why does it occur so ? (I don't know much about computers, I'm trying to :) ).

Google couldn't help me. All the links showed how to make windows use less RAM.

Thanks ! :)

Comment: 512 RAM ? You really might wanna increase that size. Modern applications are all very demanding on RAM.  At least if you have enough space on hard drive, 1 GB swap file added would be nice too. (Let me know if you want to do that).  As for window size . . . I would guess it does affect memory used, because the smaller the window the less pixels have to be drawn on screen, but I don't have hard evidence for that yet

Comment: By Atom, do you mean the Atom text editor? I think you could find lighter editors unless you have a very specific reason for continuing to use Atom.

Comment: Resizing any window will not change any ram usage. these are two different things you are talking about.

Comment: What are those things?

Comment: by two things i mean that resizing and ram

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how resizing does not affect the RAM.

Comment: As he told that he has only 512mb ram, resizing will have negligible affect on ram.

Comment: Ar?e you aware that temporary data is stored in the ram, hence resizing a window with _pixels to memorize_ would and should affect the RAM

Comment: yes temporary data are stored in ram but i guess resizing any window will decrease pixel but will have densly loaded pixel

Comment: @DKBose Yes, the Atom Text Editor. I just like the UI. Which would you recommend, considering my RAM ?

Comment: Programs like opera or Atom use your graphics card quite heavily - when you make the window smaller, the graphics card and CPU need to draw less pixels, thus making it faster.

Comment: @JonasCz So resizing  affects speed of only those apps which are a bit heavy on graphics and memory, right ?